# ATTINY85 measuring internal voltage

Tags: voltage, avr, attiny, voltage-measurement

I'm using an ATTINY85 for a portable application that uses a Lithium-ion battery; therefor I need to monitor the battery voltage so I don't kill the battery. Is there a way to go about this without using another pin? or using the reset pin? **NOTE: assume that there will be no regulated voltage such as 3.3V or the like. (this is because the circuit only uses one battery and should never go above spec; and saves on cost)

Comment: The voltage regulation is not an issue since there is an internal voltage reference. You do have to have one of the ADC pins available (Reset is one of them). Using the reset pin as an ADC pin could cause some problems programming the firmware though.

Comment: I've read if I disable it I'll have to use a HVL programmer to program it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Setting REFS[2:0] to `0bX00` will use V<sub>CC</sub> as the voltage reference, and setting MUX[3:0] to `0b1100` will use the internal bandgap voltage as the voltage to measure (see §17.13 from [the datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf)). From there, the full range of 1023 will tell you what V<sub>CC</sub> is in relation to the bandgap voltage. So take (1.1*10*1023=) 11253 (or an appropriately scaled equivalent) and divide it by the measured value in order to get the approximate value of V<sub>CC</sub> in tenths of volts.

Comment: I might be wrong, but this sounds like an example of what @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams said...  http://digistump.com/wiki/digispark/quickref

Comment: @curtis: Indeed it is.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can. I made a library https://github.com/cano64/ArduinoSystemStatus it also works with ATTiny85. In addition to measuring a voltage on VCC pin, with this library you can measure voltage on any analog pin (without need for regulated VCC), get free RAM, go to sleep and wake up after button press and more...